# Compute exponential moving average using roll apply function in R

Tags: r, rollapply

I am aware of the normal way of computing exponential moving average using inbuilt function EMA(). Want to compute the EMA using rollapply function.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use EMA with rollapply, since EMA already has the built-in rolling funciton.

Example: data_new <- data %>% mutate(new_col = EMA(x, n=10))

If you insist on using both rollapply and EMA, you can define a function with EMA first:

compute_EMA <- fun(x){ return(EMA(x, n=10))}

Then:

data_new <- data %>% mutate(new_col = rollapply(x, width = 10, FUN = compute_EMA, fill = NA, align = "right")